# Trying to connect from Azure hosted PHP app to SQL Server but got an error (ODBC)

Tags: php, sql-server, azure

I have been trying to connect from *Azure* hosted PHP application to *Azure* hosted SQL Server but got an error saying

> This extension requires the microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server

I guess this is a setting in the *Azure* portal for the *App service* but had no luck finding it.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You will require to install ODBC driver and SQLCMD, see guidelines [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/windows/) if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install ODBC driver through SSH panel.

1. Open SSH console from azure portal:

[image]

2. Run fallowing commands:

> apt-get install sudo -y
>
> apt-get install apt-transport-https
>
> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install -y gnupg2
>
> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
>
> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list >
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17